# How to reuse selector for color-different buttons in android?

Tags: android

There is button's selector file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#686b70"/>

        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#595b61" />

        <corners android:radius="8dip" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#686b70"/>

        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#595b61" />

        <corners android:radius="8dip" />
    </shape>

</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#868c95"/>

        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#7c818b" />

        <corners android:radius="8dip" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I just need change the `android:color` of solid and stroke to create a new selector. So I'm wondering is there any way to reuse this selector for color-different buttons.

Comment: You need to create selector and shape using java code programatically.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia xml cannot do this?

Comment: As you said you want it dynamically. And xmls are at compiletime. You can not write xml at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these code snippet may helps you

**Create Shape Runtime**

```
ShapeDrawable shapeSelected = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        shapeSelected.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
        shapeSelected.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        shapeSelected.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(1);

        ShapeDrawable shapeNormal = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        shapeSelected.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
        shapeSelected.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        shapeSelected.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(1);
```

**Create Selector at runtime**

```
StateListDrawable states =new StateListDrawable();
    Resources res = getResources();
    states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},shapeSelected);
    states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused}, shapeSelected);
    states.addState(new int[] {}, shapeNormal);
```

**Set as background of your views**

```
yourButton.setBackground(states);
```

Comment: Just a small implementation of this: https://gist.github.com/creativepsyco/8c2d05803a5193c187ef